# Vue 3 composition API and access to Vue instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

In `main.js` I have something like this:

```
import { myUtilFunc} from './helpers';
Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$myUtilFunc', { value: myUtilFunc });
```

In this way I have acess to `myUtilFunc` across whole application with `this.$myUtilFunc`

But how can I achieve the same in `setup()` method in Vue 3 if I don't have access to `this`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Use `provide`/`inject`

**Provide**

```js
const app = createApp(App);
app.provide('someVarName', someVar);  // `Provide` a variable to all components here
```

**Inject**:

```
// In *any* component
const { inject } = Vue;
...
setup() {
  const someVar = inject('someVarName');   // injecting variable in setup
}
```

Note that you don't have to provide from the app root, but can also `provide` from any component to only its sub-components:

```js
// In *any* component
setup() {
  ...
},
provide() {
  return {
    someVarName: someVar
  }
}
```

---

#### *Original answer*

*[**Edit**:  While my original answer below is still useful for `context` properties, it's no longer recommended to use `context.root`, which is no longer mentioned in the [guide](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-setup.html#context) and may soon be deprecated.]*

In Vue 3, `setup` has an optional second argument for `context`.  You can access the Vue instance through `context.root` instead of `this`:

```js
setup(props, context) {
  context.root.$myUtilFunc  // same as `this.$myUtilFunc` in Vue 2
}
```

Things you can access through `context`:

```
context.attrs
context.slots
context.parent
context.root
context.emit
```

Comment: ````app.provide('someVarName', someVar);```` Is the same that ````app.config.globalProperties.myGlobalVariable```` ? which is the difference?

Answer (score 6):

While Dan's answer is correct, I would like to provide an alternative mentioned in the comments to the accepted answer. There are pros and cons to each, so, you need to choose based on your needs.

To understand why the code below works, it is important to remember, that provided properties are transitive in the tree of components. I.e. `inject('foo')` will look for 'foo' in every parent going up the hierarchy all the way to the `app`; there is no need to declare anything in the middle wrappers.

So, we can write something like this, where globalDateFormatter() is just an example function we want to use in any component down the tree:

**main.js**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

const globalDateFormatter = (date) => {
    return '[' + date.toLocaleString() + ']'
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.provide('globalDateFormatter', globalDateFormatter) // <-- define here
app.mount('#app')
```

And then, in some **DeepDownComponent.vue**:

```
<template>
  <p> {{ fmt(new Date()) }} </p>
</template>

<script>
import { inject } from 'vue'
export default {
    setup(){
        const fmt = inject('globalDateFormatter', x => x.toString()) 
        //           ^-- use here, optional 2nd parameter is the default
        return {fmt}
    }
}
</script>
```

Obviously, you can directly import and use `provide` and `inject` with the following signatures

```
provide<T>(key: InjectionKey<T> | string, value: T): void
```

and

```
inject<T>(key: InjectionKey<T> | string, defaultValue: T): T
```

anywhere in your code, doesn't have to be `app.provide()`

You can also provide values, even the global store, like this, just don't forget to use `ref()` or `reactive()` as needed.

In short, whenever you would prefer dependency injection, provide/inject are your friends.