# Vue composition API use VueAxios?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vue-component, vuejs3

I am in *main.js* importing *vue-axios*

main.js

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';
import App from './App.vue';

const app = createApp(App);

app.use(VueAxios, axios);
app.mount('#app');
```

and App.vue

```js
export default {
  name: 'App',
  setup() {
   axios.get('xxxx').then((res) => {console.log(res)}); // is not working
  }
};
```

but it seems Vue composition API setup can't get axios?  So it must be used in App.vue `import axios from 'axios'`?

```js
import axios from 'axios';
 
export default {
  name: 'App',
  setup() {
   axios.get('xxxx').then((res) => {console.log(res)});
  }
};
```

My environment is *vite*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This wouldn't work in any version of Vue without an import:

```js
axios.get(...)
```

Even in Vue 2, you have to use one of these if you use vue-axios:

```js
this.axios.get(...)
this.$http.get(...)
Vue.axios.get(...)
```

The composition API has no `this` access in the component, so `vue-axios` doesn't help much.

Comment: thx, but I use the composition API, it seems that import must be used on that page.

Comment: Yes, that was the point of my explanation.  It doesn't work without an import

Comment: But there are other ways to give access through the root component in Vue 3:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60202724/vue-3-composition-api-and-access-to-vue-instance/60204181#60204181

Comment: oh! maybe use provide/inject is goods idea! very thx!!

Answer (score 5):

generally I'd do something like this ( except I modularize all the api calling into a "service" rather than inlining it into the view code.)

```
import axios from 'axios';
import {onMounted} from 'vue'
 
export default {
  name: 'App',
  setup() {

   onMounted(async () => {
     let res = await axios.get('xxxx')
     console.log(res)
   });
  }
};
```