# How to use $axios Nuxt module inside of setup() from composition API?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-composition-api

The docs say to use `this.$axios.$get()` inside of `methods/mounted/etc`, but that throws `TypeError: _this is undefined` when called inside of `setup()`. Is `$axios` compatible with the composition API?

To clarify, I'm specifically talking about the axios nuxt plugin, not just using axios generically. https://axios.nuxtjs.org/

So for instance, something like this throws the error above

```
export default {
  setup: () => {
    const data = this.$axios.$get("/my-url");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
import { useContext } from '@nuxtjs/composition-api';

setup() {
  const { $axios } = useContext();
}
```

Comment: Ahhh, I'd forgotten about useContext(). I'll give this a try tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so with the usual configuration of a Nuxt plugin aka
`plugins/vue-composition.js`

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueCompositionApi from '@vue/composition-api'

Vue.use(VueCompositionApi)
```

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
plugins: ['~/plugins/vue-composition']
```

You can then proceed with a test page and run this kind of code to have a successful axios get

```js
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import { onMounted } from '@vue/composition-api'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  setup() {
    onMounted(async () => {
      const res = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
      console.log(res)
    })
  },
}
</script>
```

I'm not sure about how to import axios globally in this case but since it's composition API, you do not use the options API keys (`mounted` etc...).

Thanks to this post for the insight on how to use Vue3: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65015450/8816585

Comment: I should have been more clear. I'm referring to the nuxt plugin specifically: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/. I already have composition api working. The issue is that I cannot call this.$axios per the plugin docs https://axios.nuxtjs.org/